# JavaScript Increment (Double Checking)

Tags: javascript

I seem to have bad internet, and the only site loading is StackOverflow and CodePen. I just wanted to double check:
Lets say I have this JS code.

```
var energy = 100;
var day = 3;
var energyCounter = document.getElementById("energyC");
var dayCounter = document.getElementById("dayC");
var choice = prompt("What is your action? A1, A2, or A3?");
switch(choice)  {
    case 'A1':
        if(choice === "A1")  {
            energy -- 10;
        }
        break;
    case 'A2':
        if(choice === "A2")  {
            energy -- 25;
            day -- 1;
        }
        break;
    case 'A2':
        if(choice === "A3")  {
            energy ++ 5;
        }
    break;
    default:
        alert("I didn't understand.");
}
```

If it goes as I think, if the user types 'A1', then it should decrease the CURRENT `energy` by 10, and that's that. If they type 'A2', then it should decrease the CURRENT `energy` by 25 and the current `day` by 1, and finally if they type 'A3', it should increase the CURRENT `energy` by 5, right? (Of course, there's flaws & the default case, but it's a sample.)

Comment: You don't need to check with `if` when you've already done `switch`. That's "double checking" indeed :)

Comment: That is not valid javascript, and you have "A2" choice twice.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari If you read the whole post...

`(Of course,t here's flaws & the default case, but it's a sample.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do `energy -= 10;` or `energy += 10;`, these are short forms for `energy = energy - 10;` etc.